# Android HorizontalScrollView disable scrolling

Tags: android

I have HorizontalScrollView with long view as a child, so HorizontalScrollView is scrollable and can scroll its child horizontally. 
Is there any possibility to block that? I don't want user to be able to scroll the view.

Comment: The scroll view is for scrolling! If you don't want user scrolling, choose another way other than using scrollView. You can use animation instead.

Answer (score 20):

My suggestion is to use an **OnTouchListener**, for example:

In `onCreate` Method

---

```
HorziontalScrollView scrollView= (HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouch());
```

---

And has a class:

---

```
private class OnTouch implements OnTouchListener
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: That saved my day! Actually, i spent a hour looking how to disable small scrolling in TabLayout. But i completely forgot that it's kind of scrollview! That works in my case as well.

Comment: It saved my day. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the way how to implement that.

Just need to create my own  HorizontalScrollView and override onTouchEvent method

```
public class MyHSV extends HorizontalScrollView {

    public MyHSV(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    public MyHSV(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public MyHSV(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    void init(Context context) {
        // remove the fading as the HSV looks better without it
        setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
        setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // Do not allow touch events.
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // Do not allow touch events.
        return false;
    }

}
```

And then in the xml file

```
<pathToClass.MyHSV xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:id="@+id/myHSV>

</pathToClass.MyHSV>
```