# How to disable scrolling in HorizontalScrollView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.1.1-lollipop

What i want in pictures:
[image]

On the words: i want to **disable scrolling with formatting** text inside `HorizontalScrollView`.

Part of XML:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/review_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tt_review_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Some long text"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"/>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</ScrollView>
```

Method(doesn't works):

```
private void setTtAreaWrapContent(boolean value) {
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = textField.getLayoutParams();
    if(value) { // Wrap content
        textField.setWidth(scrollView.getWidth());
    } else { // Scroll
        params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    }
    textField.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Comment: What is the point of using a HorizontalScrollView if you don't want to scroll at all?

Comment: @AritraRoy, I want to scroll text if the user has selected it in the settings.

Comment: [DIsable horizontal scroll view] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462126/android-horizontalscrollview-disable-scrolling

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple way to do this.

Check if the user wants to scroll or not and then store it in a boolean variable, `shouldScroll`.

Now do this in `onCreate`,

```
HorziontalScrollView scrollView= (HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView);

if(!shouldScroll)
scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouch());
```

You also need to define a class `OnTouch` extending the `OnTouchListener`

```
private class OnTouch implements OnTouchListener
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return true;
    }
}
```

Now for the TextView formatting, just use `android:singleLine="false"` or use `android:width="0dip"`

Comment: Maybe I do not say so ... Look: http://snag.gy/fOhiQ.jpg ; Yes, I can not scroll, but the text is still cut off. One of ways is put there TextView without ScrollView, but can i just format text to screen size?

Answer (score -2):

I had absolutely the same need for code, so I initially proposed a ViewSwitcher with the same layouts, but one with HorizontalScrollView and one without it. And switch to the corresponding view depending on the setting.

However, I found an easier solution. After recreation of the Activity (when wrapping settings are changed by the user), use the code in the onCreate methode:

```
  if (isWrapContent)
    {
        View mTV = findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
        HorizontalScrollView myHSV = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.my_hsv);
        ViewGroup parent =  (ViewGroup) myHSV.getParent();
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = myHSV.getLayoutParams();
        int index = parent.indexOfChild(myHSV);
        myHSV.removeAllViews();
        parent.removeView(myHSV);
        parent.addView(mTV, index, params);
    }
```

You need to use your id's and variables correspondingly.

It will remove the horizontal scrollview with the embedded textview and then reinsert the textview.

My answer provides direct and valid answer on how the asked issue could be resolved instead of freezing the horizontal scrollview or wondering about the point of the question, as it is done in the other comments and answers.