# Decide wether scroll was user initiated or programmatically triggered?

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview

Some logic need to be executed in a `HorizontalScrollView` listener only if `HorizontalScrollView` was scrolled by user, and not me was who called `horizontalScrollView.scrollBy(dx, 0);` method at on other code part.

With flag - programmatic call was started, finished - can not really fix problem, because there is a small delay between `scrollBy` method call and triggering event handler. But in this time frame even user could touch and scroll `HorizontalScrollView`.

What approach would you suggest?

```
horizontalScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged() {

            if (horizontalState == 0) {
                horizontalState = 2;
            }

            if (horizontalState == 2) {

                int d = ...;

                if (d != 0) {
                    userSettingRecycleView.scrollBy(d , 0);

                } else {
                    horizontalState = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

---

```
userSettingRecycleView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy){

                if (horizontalState == 1) {

                    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                    horizontalScrollView.scrollBy(dx, 0);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

                if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {

                    ItemUserSettingRatingActivity.horizontalState = 1;
                }

                if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE || newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING) {
                    ItemUserSettingRatingActivity.horizontalState = 0;
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to disable user touches in range between your programm `scrool` events. That is, use [those](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10481239/1979882) classes to create your custom `HorisontalScrollView` and to enable/disable taps' catch in a programm way.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING`

```
private val scrollListener = object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView?, newState: Int) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
        if (newState == SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) ViewHelpers.hideKeyboard(activity)
    }
}
```